# Magento 2 data migration RuntimeException

Tags: magento2, composer, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

I am learning how to convert Magento 1.x to Magento 2.x

I installed fresh `Magento ver. 1.9.3.8` from GitHub mirror and fresh `Magento 2.2.3` using composer

```
maddy@maddy:/var/www/html/magento-composer$ sudo php bin/magento --version
[sudo] password for maddy: 
Magento CLI version 2.2.3
```

maddy@maddy:/var/www/html/magento-composer$

In magento 1.9.3 i created one product, one category and placed one order now i am trying to migrate it to fresh Magento 2.

i followed this link [Install Data Migration Tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html)  to install the toool.

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.2.3
```

but when i run above commands i got

```
  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  You must pass the type and a url. Example: php composer.phar config reposit  
  ories.foo vcs https://bar.com                                                


config [-g|--global] [-e|--editor] [-a|--auth] [--unset] [-l|--list] [-f|--file FILE] [--absolute] [--] [<setting-key>] [<setting-value>]...

maddy@maddy:/var/www/html/magento-composer$
```

I am not able to solve this, can anyone see what is the issue.

**Update:** if i run below command i got some error realated to memory

```
maddy@maddy:/var/www/html/magento-composer$ composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.2.3

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
The following exception is caused by a lack of memory and not having swap configured
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors for details


  [ErrorException]                                   
  proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory 



maddy@maddy:/var/www/html/magento-composer$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3868        2758         105         303        1005         476
Swap:           475         470           5
maddy@maddy:/var/www/html/magento-composer$
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

`composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com`

then

`composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.2.3`

**EDIT**: Second question:

`proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory`

Adjust PHP memory_limit

Check also in `var/www/html/magento-composer/.user.ini` - You will see there some php config values.

Validate the change with `php -i | grep memory_limit` in console.

Comment: I already increased PHP memory limit in ini file but no success

Comment: @inrsaurabh Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Please execute this command from your Magento root directory to migrate **Magento1 to Magento2**,

- composer update
- composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git
  https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool
- composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.2.3
- php bin/magento migrate:settings
  vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml
- php bin/magento migrate:data --reset
  vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml
- Flush all Magento 2 cache types
- Reindex all Magento 2 indexers

Replace 1.9.2.4 with your Magento1 version.

I hope this will help you.